# Why java Iterator interface should be implemented as inner class?

Tags: java, iterator, inner-classes

I recently read a book "The Java Tutorials" 3rd edition.
It talks about inner class implementation as the picture shows.

In the 3rd paragraph, it says "The Stack class itself should not implement the Iterator interface, because...".

I cannot find any reason that Stack class should not implement Iterator. The reason given is NOT persvasive.

Could you explain it?

[image: Inner class]
[image: Inner class]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fundamentally, an iterator is stateful - it needs to know *where* it's pointing within the collection. That doesn't belong as part of the collection itself - and the explanation given is the right one... it's entirely possible to have two independent iterator objects, iterating over the same collection object. How would you model that if the collection itself implemented the Iterator interface? It's *possible* (e.g. creating a new instance of the collection which in turn held a reference to the original collection), but it would be really ugly.

There are separate concerns here:

- The collection of data
- A cursor positioned within the collection

Separate concerns => separate classes.

The simplest way of persuading yourself of this is probably to try to implement your own collection though - and then have multiple iterators. For example, you might want to try:

```
List<String> foo = new MyListImplementation<String>();
foo.add("a");
foo.add("b");

// The enhanced for loop uses Iterable/Iterator for non-arrays
for (String x : foo) {
    for (String y : foo) {
        System.out.println(x + " " + y);
    }
}
```

That *should* print out:

```
a a
a b
b a
b b
```

Try implementing it without having two classes, and see how you do, bearing separation of concerns in mind.

Answer (score 4):

The stack should not implement Iterator itself because then you could have only one iterator at a time, and iterating over a stack would change the stack.

For the latter issue, notice that the nested class has a "currentItem" field.  This field would need to be in "Stack", and would change when next() is called.  Iterating over a collection should not change the collection.

The first problem is more serious: suppose two people iterate over the stack (or one method wishes to create two iterators over the stack).  Then if `iterator()` returned `this`, the two iterators would be the same thing.  Calling `next()` on one would move the other.  Chaos.

Answer (score 2):

A `Stack` cannot be its own `Iterator` because a Stack supports more than one Iterator.

You might want to iterate over the Stack more than once. These iterations might occur at different times, or even the same time. Multiple iterations at the same time clearly require multiple objects. Multiple iterations at different times require multiple objects because the Iterator interface does not support returning to the start.

Comment: "two objects could not enumerate the items in Stack concurrently". What are the two objects? Are they instances of Stack?

Comment: That's poorly worded. It's referring to two different entities that both want to iterate over the same Stack. Those entities might be two different objects with a reference to the same Stack, or they could be different methods or different threads.

Comment: Thx, the KEY is several "entities" that hold the same reference to the Stack or the Stack Iterator.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 reasons I can think of off the top of my head.

#### Multiple *types* of iterators

You may want multiple types of iterators that iterate in different ways. For instance, both a Forward Iterator and a Backward Iterator (iterates from end of the container to beginning).

#### Multiple *instances* of iterators

If you have a multiple pass algorithm and/or nested loops, each loop may want its own iterator that keeps track of where it is in the container independent of the other iterators.

---

It would be difficult if not impossible to support these functionalities with the `Iterator` interface implemented in the `Stack` class.

Comment: any special reason for a large font?

Comment: Yeah. This is reasonable. But I still don't know the reason given in the text book. "two objects could not enumerate the items in Stack concurrently". What are the two objects? Are they instances of Stack?

Comment: @Zachery I think the book is misleading in that regard. I think the scenario its envisioning is if you have a stack `s`, and then you have two objects `foo` and `bar` which each have a pointer to `s` (maybe `s` was passed into the ctor of the `foo` and `bar` instances). If these objects want to iterate over `s`, they would get in each other's way unless they had their own, private iterators. More generally, you could also have a single function/method which needs two iterators to the same `Stack` instance. You don't need the "separate objects" to run into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the discussion, the inner class will have access to private data of the Stack class, so in this way, the Stack class will manage to handle the client programmer an object, or multiple objects(the iterator(s), and still these object will be able to access the class and to provide separate iteration over the collection.